# Excel - interpolate between two values

Tags: excel

On the ''Sheet1'' I have hourly values of temperatures, that looks like this:

```
Time                 Value
1.1.2017 0:00:00     4
1.1.2017 1:00:00     8
1.1.2017 2:00:00     0
```

and that goes till the end of the year.

On the ''Sheet2'' I have 15-minutes time data, and at least I'd like to get "Value II" where the value is the same during whole hour. Ideal would be to get "Value III" where the values are linear interpolation between two numbers.

```
Time                 Value II   Value III
1.1.2017 0:00:00     4          4 
1.1.2017 0:15:00     4          5
1.1.2017 0:30:00     4          6
1.1.2017 0:45:00     4          7 
1.1.2017 1:00:00     8          8 
1.1.2017 1:15:00     8          6
1.1.2017 1:30:00     8          4 
1.1.2017 1:45:00     8          2
1.1.2017 2:00:00     0          0
```

For "Value II" I tried:

```
 IF(AND(DATE(YEAR(A2);MONTH(A2);DAY(A2))=DATE(YEAR(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$1000);MONTH(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$1000);DAY(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$1000));HOUR(A2)=HOUR(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$1000));Sheet1!$B$2:$B$1000;"")
```

But I get `""` every time.

For the "Value III" I know the math formula when you interpolate `r` numbers between two numbers `a` and `b` then the distance `d` between interpolated numbers is:

```
d = (b-a)/(r+1)
```

And the values of those interpolated numbers are:

```
r1 = a + d
r2 = r1 + d   or   r2 = a + 2*d
r3 = r2 + d   or   r3 = a + 3*d
```

But in excel I don't even know where to start, maybe something with `FORECAST`.

Comment: Are you allowed to add extra columns to the two sheets?

Comment: Yes, I'll probably do it that way. I'll split date and time in two columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would do to get Value II:

On Sheet1, add a column that will split off the year, month, day, and hour. I put it in column B and used this formula: `=YEAR(A2)&MONTH(A2)&DAY(A2)&HOUR(A2)`

It looks like this:
[image]

Then go to Sheet2 and add the same column there too. I put it in column B just like I did in sheet1. Once again I used this formula: `=YEAR(A2)&MONTH(A2)&DAY(A2)&HOUR(A2)`

[image]

Once all that is done you can use VLOOKUP in column C of Sheet1.

The formula is `=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1a!$B$2:$C$1000,2,FALSE)`

Adding the extra columns provides a reliable way for the VLOOKUP to function, and eliminates the need to deal with the minutes and seconds.